# Ansible create users with Key Authenication

Tags: ansible

when creating user(s) with SSH PasswordAuthenication, there doesn't appear to be an issue. 
However, creating users(s) with SSH Key Authentication, I'm not sure I understand the workflow.

I want to create a user account with SSH Key Authentication, across other linux servers. 
On my admin box,  I can provision these users with ansible, across many other
linux servers with Password Authentication,

I want SSH Key Authentication.

How can you provision a new account across many servers it's own user SSH Key?

I seems, you have the following workflow with ansible;

- enable PasswordAuthenication in sshd_config, among all servers (including the admin system).
- create the account(s)
- have the new user login (admin box), and create there own SSH Key.
- The new user submits the public key to the provisioning admin.
- The provisioning admin copies the key to all servers,
- then disable PasswordAuthenicaiton in sshd_config

Does that sound right, or is there a better way ?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the [authorized_key_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html) as well. The flow to add a user to a server with a specific ssh key should be:

```
---

- name: Ensure user is present.
  user:
    name: user
    state: present

- name: Set authorized key took from file
  authorized_key:
    user: user
    state: present
    key: id_rsa.pub
```

Disabling password authentication should be part of the in initial Ansible setup.